# Possible to combine an Indexer with DefaultMemberAttribute?  MSDN has a broken sample

Tags: c#, attributes, ienumerable, msdn

The [following MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.readonlyenveloperecipientcollection%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) shows something that doesn't appear valid to the compiler when combining this header

```
[DefaultMemberAttribute("Item")] 
public abstract class ReadOnlyEnvelopeRecipientCollection : IEnumerable<EnvelopeRecipient>, IEnumerable
```

with [this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.readonlyenveloperecipientcollection.item%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)

```
public abstract EnvelopeRecipient [int index] { get; }
```

The compiler throws this error

> "Cannot specify DefaultMember attribute on a type containing an indexer"

Is the documentation incorrect or is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Why would you want an indexer to be the default member? What logic is there to it? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am looking at MSFT documentation and trying to understand it.  I don't get it, so it may be a documentation bug.

Comment: So you don't really need this, just trying to understand the documentation? The documentation must be wrong, because you can see the compiler error for yourself. End of story?

Comment: Some odds that this was auto-generated from a COM interface, given that it is Exchange and that having the indexer be the default property in COM isn't a problem.  C# doesn't permit it so this is rather academic.